# Expert advice needed on UIwebview content fit

Tags: ios, ipad

I am facing a issue with the UIWebview on iPad.
I have to show a webpage in the webview with page fitted in webview properly.

the webpage has the following meta tag 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

the page looks ok if the webpage has height and width equals to device.
But if i change the webview height & width. the webpage stop fitting properly in the webview.

Is there anything i can do to fit the webpage properly in the webview. irrespective of the webview height and width.

I already tried all other questions on the stack overflow. but no success..

Can anybody help me on this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution using

```
 [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:  
 [NSString stringWithFormat:  
 @"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%d;', false); ",(int)webview.frame.size.width]];`
```

Thanks to all..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the scales page to fit in your web views attribute inspector?

[image]

Comment: Yes already tried but no success.. the webpage fits properly if the view size is equal to device width and height but if i change it using setFrame it stops fitting in the webview.